# Crash when adding AdMob to Firebase project

Tags: ios, firebase, admob

I've got an iOS project using Firebase, it's working fine. However, when I try to add AdMob, the app crashes when launching:

> "'GADInvalidInitializationException', reason: 'The Google Mobile Ads
>   SDK was initialized incorrectly. Google AdMob publishers should follow
>   instructions here:
>   https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-ios-update-plist to include
>   the AppMeasurement framework, set the -ObjC linker flag, and set
>   GADApplicationIdentifier with a valid App ID. Google Ad Manager
>   publishers should follow instructions here:
>   https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/ad-manager-ios-update-plist'"

Just by adding `pod 'Firebase/AdMob'` to the Podfile  already produces this crash.

Then I added `GADApplicationIdentifier` to the `GoogleService-Info.plist`:

```
<key>GADApplicationIdentifier</key>
<string>APP_KEY</string>
```

Same thing, crash.

The app is linked to Firebase in the AdMob app site.

Anybody has any tips on this? Google's docs don't seem to be up to date, making a lot of confusion about AdMob implementation with/without Firebase.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update the app's Info.plist - the file set in the `INFOPLIST_FILE` Build Setting - not `GoogleService-Info.plist`.

Comment: Wow, that did it. Thank you very much.

Comment: I spend 6 hours to find this issue :(. Setting GADIsAdManagerApp to YES also works..

Answer (score 3):

**Info.plist** add following line not **GoogleService-Info.plist.**

```
 <key>GADIsAdManagerApp</key>
 <true/>
```

also add key of **Google Ads Mob**

```
 <key>GADApplicationIdentifier</key>
 <string>key-value</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

**In Xcode 15:**
First have to update `Info.plist` following this:
https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-ios-update-plist

After that manually add the `-ObjC` linker flag to Other Linker Flags in your target's build settings

[image]